# Сравнение целых и остатков

Tags: javascript, циклы, if, for

Посчитайте сумму чисел на промежутке от 1 до 1000 включительно. Потом посчитайте целую часть от деления этой суммы на число 1234, а так же остаток от деления. Выведите в консоль true если целая часть от деления больше остатка от деления и false в другом случае

Основные требования:
Реализовать логику и вывести в консоль результат - булеан

!!!В данном упражнении нельзя использовать if/else конструкцию даже если вы с ней знакомы :)
Помогите реализовать без if/else...
Написал ток первую часть кода дальше я хз как без тернарных справитса

```
    let result = 0;
       for(let i = 0;i <= 1000; i++) {
        result+=i; 
        }
```

Comment: и какие именно у вас проблемы то?

Comment: вас, возможно, удивит, но в консоль можно просто вывести булевое выражение `a>b`, которое будет преобразовано к строке. Использование тернарного оператора, также не противоречит условиям задачи

Comment: как тогда правильно записать целую часть от деления и остаток от деления

Comment: `a/b` - даст целую часть, `a%b` - даст остаток

Comment: стоит, наверное, упомянуть, что сумма арифметической прогрессии также успешно вычисляется без использования цикла

Answer (score 0):

маленькая подсказка (делать можно по другому, но принцип тот же как выводить булевы типы

```
let answer = ['Не верно', 'Все правильно'];
console.log(answer(Number(15 < 16)));
```

Comment: но ведь вывести надо `true` или `false`

Comment: @Grundy да кому это надо цель задачи читать? и так сойдет